# Visual basic first element of array

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, element

I'm just starting with visual basic.

The first element in an array

i.e. `dim y(9)` as Integer

Will that have elements `0-8` or `1-9` in?

i.e. if I did

```
y(1) = 84
```

does that make the first or second element in the array equal to 84?

I've looked at a few online sources and I'm a bit confuzzled.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first position for arrays in VB.NET is zero; same rules apply to any in-built collection/function requiring indexing and to other .NET languages, like C#. On the other hand, "old" VB (VB6 and older or VBA) has zero as first index for arrays and one for in-built functions (this is somehow confusing for people coming from VB to VB.NET). What is common to all the VB versions (.NET and older ones) and different to other languages like C#, is that the number used when instantiating the array (9 in `y(9)`) does not indicate its size but its last index (the size of `y(9)` is 10).

In summary, your array includes 10 positions: from 0 to 9.

Comment: Cheers, that's where I was getting confused.

Comment: @DanMc Is a bit confusing issue. Now you are in .NET and zero rules everything :)

Comment: "old" VB (VB6 and older or VBA) , like Pascal, has any arbitrary integer as first position: Dim myArray(-3 to +3). This was sometimes confusing for people coming from c.

Comment: @david Actually, that seems weird for almost any programming language. Even the traditional VB feature of 1-based arrays is pretty exceptional. Also a big deal of languages are C-based and so no real need of coming from actual C. In any case, that scenario is much more common nowadays under a slightly different format: keys of a key-value collection/dictionary where indices can be virtually anything (integers, strings or whatever). Most of modern languages support this kind of structures. Efficiency is a different story. Basic (0-, 1-based) arrays are usually way much more efficient.

Comment: @varocarbas I don't do ARM assembly, but looking at my 8086 assembly, zero based arrays are not very more efficient - at best, hoisting the start and end points out to the high level code is handled efficiently by the compiler, which is much more likely when the compiler actually has semantic information. And I specify c because prior to c there was discussion about the reason for zero based arrays (cf Dijkstra), and efficiency was not the reason - (cf FORTRAN).

Comment: @david As explained in detail (in the comments I have deleted because of considering that this whole thing is pretty offtopic), I don't think that your statement is right or even relevant here. I also have problems to understand this attitude of writing a somehow-offtopic comment years after I posted this answer and then taking various months to answer to my polite reply. I am a pretty tolerant guy always ready to understand others(' peculiarities), but your behaviour makes little sense to me. So, I will ignore (and perhaps even flag) any future comment of yours on these lines.

Answer (score 1):

The elements in the array start from 0 in VB.NET

A sample example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wak0wfyt.aspx):

[image]

You may also find this interesting to read:- **[Why numbering should start at zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)**